# How to insert multiple rows using insert while selecting data from another table

Tags: mysql

```
insert INTO table1 (price,service_id,country_id)VALUES(2.00,(SELECT id from table2), (SELECT id from table3))
```

It shows error.

Table 1-
id, price, service_id, country_id

Table 2-
id, service_name

Table 3-
id, country_name

Comment: Usually an error is quite helpfull in telling you what's wrong! Also helpfull for others to help you.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

When inserting in `mysql` using select query, you don't need the `values()` anymore.

Try this:

```
insert INTO table1 (price,service_id,country_id) Select t2.ID, t3.ID from table_2 t2, table_3 t3
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_insert_into_select.asp) is one example.